# fixed-effects (n observations) removed because of only 0 outcomes [R]

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression

I am running a fixed effects negative binomial regression with R using the `finegbin()` function of the fixest package and received:

`228 fixed-effects (1,140 observations) removed because of only 0 outcomes.`

Can someone briefly explain to me what exactly is meant by that statement?
Also, what are the implications for my regression model? I analyze 267 districts, so 85% of my units of analysis are dropped...

Comment: Please explain which software you used and the relative command. Add this information by updating your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you have several factors (i.e. categorical covariates) in your model. E.g. you have country (e.g. US, Canada, Germany and Andorra), age group (e.g. <18, 18 to <65 and >=65) and previous disease history (yes/no). You are trying to fit a negative binomial model like `events ~ 0 + country + agegroup + diseasehist`.

If it then so happens that for the 5 people from Andorra 0 events happened and for the 1 person aged <18 also 0 events happened, then a traditional maximum likelihood approach becomes problematic. Arguably, the maximum likelihood estimate of the event rate for Andorra (and similarly for the age group < 18 years) is 0, but that's tricky to deal with, because it's at the edge of the parameter space for rates (i.e. $(0, \infty)$ as rates cannot be negative). Even worse, you typically/by default work on the log-scale when you do negative binomial distribution, which means you don't get numerical convergence (i.e. the likelihood will become higher and higher as you estimate on the log-scale becomes a negative number of bigger and bigger magnitude). The package you use seems to remove variables from the model that cause such problems (but in some cases, they might of course be very important variables that predict very well that no events will happen for certain people).

This is the same problem as complete separation/quasi-complete separation in logistic regression and Cox regression. So, it would seem obvious to try the same solutions. Out of the known obvious solutions, the Firth's correction and exact negative binomial regression are not things I've seen implemented for negative binomial regression, so the main obvious solution is a Bayesian approach. E.g. the `brms` R package provides a convenient interface for fitting Bayesian negative binomial regression (the parameterization used is [described here](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/articles/brms_families.html#binary-and-count-data-models-1)).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

Comment: Would it increase my model fit, if drop the fixed effects and add more time-invariant covariates?